# dimensional time series data clustering

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a data set which is time-series type and contains three dimensions namely acceleration, speed and grade. I want to apply clustering to identify the clusters that have similar speed (acceleration=0, positive or negative) varying with grade. I do not know what type of clustering should i use, surely k-means cannot help me because there is a serial correlation between my data point because each point is affected by its previous point. Could you please help me with the type of clustering?

Answer (score 0):

Popular time series similarity metrics such as DTW can be implemented for multiple variates the same way as for a single variate. The most challenging part is normalization.

You then can run hierarchical clustering trivially. Do not use KMeans.